# How to identify database in SQL Server Profiler?

Tags: sql-server

In the SQL Server Profiler, I've added a filter for:

```
DatabaseName Like MyDatabase
```

I then log into the same server and run:

```
select * from MyDatabase
```

I don't see any entries in the Profiler.  I remove the above filter and run the statement again.  It shows up in the Profiler.

Any idea why it isn't working with the filter?

Also, is there a way to filter on three databases?  In other words, I want to see execution against three databases.

Comment: Are you in that database? when you log into a 'server' you are logged in a certain database automatically. Is it the one your'e filtering on? The statement you should be running would be `USE MyDatabase GO SELECT * FROM ATable`

Comment: I have the database in my FROM.  How do I view the filter where the database name is set?  It seems once you set this and create the profile, you can't go back to it.  You have to start all over.

Comment: In your example, `MyDatabase` is a table. A database in a from looks like this: `SELECT * FROM Database..Table` or this `SELECT * FROM Database.dbo.Table`

Comment: At the very least run `SELECT DB_NAME()` and identify what the current database is. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189753.aspx

Answer (score 0):

On the Events Selection tab of the Trace Properties window, hit the "Column Filters..." button and click on DatabaseName. From here you can filter to your database(s). If you double click on the "Like" group after entering your first database name, it will add another blank spot to enter a new name.

Comment: Minus the double to add another database, that is what I'm already doing.

Answer (score 0):

When you start a new trace, click the Event Selection tab and then click the "Show All Columns" checkbox. Then, scroll the window until you see the column "Database Name", and check all of the checkboxes there.
[image: Trace Properties]